# Accessing SMTP server in R-studio with wildcard search

Tags: r, ssh, scp

I have setup up SSH to my pc with access to a file server using scp. I use it to access files in R-studio (make local copy and load into R-studio) by using the R-command "shell":

```
shell("scp prod:", Serverpath,'', Localpath)
```

This uses the specific path (on server) to a specific file. I'm trying to access a file, but I only know part of the filename. How can I load the specific file into R?

Comment: Often `scp` will support basic filename globbing. For instance, `scp prod:/some/dir/pattern*.txt` should still work. (Note that this is [globbing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)), not regular expressions, though there are some similarities.)

Comment: I have tried this but in R-studio but it returns an error: scp: some/dir/pattern*.csv: No such file or directory

Comment: (I'm inferring that you used your real remote directory and filename pattern there.) If your shell is trying to expand it, then use single-quotes, ala `'prod:/path/to/pattern*.txt'`.